# Запятая в вопросительном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Столица ЮБК или центр рынка?» Верно без запятой?

Answer (score 3):

Что без запятой верно - это точно, а вот само предложение интересное. Лучше бы дать побольше контекста, чтобы оно стало понятным.

*Столица ЮБК или центр рынка?*

Мне видится предложение диалогически неполным:

*Какие приоритеты у города? (Это) столица ЮБК или центр рынка?* - простое **с однородными членами, союз одиночный.**

*Какие приоритеты у города? (Это) столица ЮБК или (это) центр рынка?* Сложносочинённое предложение, простые в нём объединены **вопросительной интонацией**.

У Лопатина:

> 5. если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой
>    побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения;
>    объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных
>    предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: Где будет собрание и кто его
>    председатель? — общая вопросительная интонация; Как тихо вокруг и как
>    чисто звездное небо! — общая восклицательная интонация; Пусть светит
>    солнце и птицы поют! — общая частица.

http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg112.php

Два номинативных, по-моему, некорректно, потому что номинативные предложения - бытийные, указывают на их реальное бытие, вопросительными они быть не могут, восклицательными - да.

С запятой трудно представить контекст, если только там будет иметься в виду пояснение: Неужели Ялта - это столица ЮБК, или центр (автомобильного) рынка? Или присоединение. Если этих условий нет - то без запятой.

Comment: *Два номинативных, по-моему, некорректно* - вот это мне непонятно. А как бы вы разобрали, к примеру, такой случай: *Острая боль или высокая температура? Тогда без очереди!*

Comment: Тоже неполное: У вас (имеется) острая боль или высокая температура? Тогда без очереди! Одно из условий номинативного - значение предикативности выражается констатирующей интонацией. https://studopedia.ru/20_8138_nominativnie-predlozheniya.html

Comment: * У вас (имеется) острая боль или высокая температура?* - Да? Спасибо, конечно, но я имел ввиду, что-то типо того, как Филипп Филиппович с Борменталем обсуждают грядущий прием. ))) Но дело не в этом, конечно. Признаю, что я жутко отстал от этих новомодных веяний - и совершенно перестал понимать зачем оно тогда нужно. Покажите мне номинативное предложение, которое таким приемом нельзя свести к неполному.  Ладно, не буду в комментах душу изливать, но я обескуражен этой систематикой...

Answer (score 0):

Перед единичным союзом «или» в простом предложении запятая не ставится. Соединены однородные члены предложения, запятая не нужна.

Comment: Однородные термин и точка на плане?